# How to transfer jsfiddle code to dreamweaver?

Tags: jquery, onload, jsfiddle, transfer

i have just figured this out http://jsfiddle.net/bUjx7/105/

but when i copy the code into dreamweaver it does not work!

I never use jquery so how do you add the library as i know it's done automatically in jsfiddle? Is it with a link in the head tag?
I tried adding

```
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</head>
```

but this doesnt work is it something to do with the onLoad?

I really don't know, I know this is a simple problem but hopefully once i know, i wont ever have to ask again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of the second dropdown in jsFiddle is "onLoad". This means any javascript you write in the script panel will be executed in an `onLoad` event handler. Since you're using jQuery, you can reproduce this behavior by using a `$(document).ready` block*:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // your code from the jsFiddle javascript panel
});
```

*[onLoad and document ready are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready), but either will work for you.

Comment: It still isn't working?? I don't know what i'm doing wrong? I have wrapped the jquery with your code and put <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> in the <head> tag? I have saved the jquery code in a .js file does that make a difference or something

Comment: Thanks for that code it worked, the only reason it didnt was because i didnt put http: in that link! oops

Comment: @Ned glad i could help. cheerio